# delete file form folder that uploaded and path stored in SQL server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I was upload number of PDF, and i store there path in SQL server.
I need to be able to delete pdf file that was saved in a folder. I've managed to get the upload & download working but the delete is baffling me.
my code is...`

```
 protected void gridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        ProductID = gridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ProductID"].ToString();
        //File Delete start//
        using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT PDF1, PDF2, PDF3 FROM Product WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", con1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductID", ProductID);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            try
            {
                string pdf1 = dt.Rows[0]["PDF1"].ToString();
                string pdf2 = dt.Rows[0]["PDF2"].ToString();
                string pdf3 = dt.Rows[0]["PDF3"].ToString();

                string strFileFullPath1 = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(pdf1);
                if (File.Exists(strFileFullPath1))
                {
                    File.Delete(strFileFullPath1);
                }
                string strFileFullPath2 = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(pdf2);
                if (File.Exists(strFileFullPath2))
                {
                    File.Delete(strFileFullPath2);
                }
                string strFileFullPath3 = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(pdf3);
                if (File.Exists(strFileFullPath3))
                {
                    File.Delete(strFileFullPath3);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why did you include a link to a picture of your code instead of just putting the code here itself?  Please fix that.

Comment: i attached a code picture

Comment: I know you did.  Why didn't you put the code here in the question itself?  We don't want to click a link to get to your code, let along look at a picture of it instead of the code itself.  Please modify your question so it includes the code itself in the body of the question.

Comment: ok i attached the code and modified my question.can you give me a solution?

Comment: Notice that someone already did....

Answer (score 1):

get the absolute path from relative path and then delete the file

```
string strFileFullPath= Server.MapPath(brangimage);
if (System.IO.File.Exists(strFileFullPath)) {
        System.IO.File.Delete(strFileFullPath);
    }
```

Comment: it didn't execute if statement, but path is exist.

Comment: are you get any exception with above code? check the path it return from the map path and manually check by directly open it from explorer

Comment: no, there is no exception with above code. if i want to download this file its ok, but i cant delete it, I check directly but it says..(ex.Message = "The relative virtual path 'C:/Users/masum/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/MapleAutomation/MapleAutomation/Content/Data/document.pdf' is not allowed here.")